# Flutter FlushBar unwinlingly hides top navigation bar while being showed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Flutter 1.17.1, iPhone XS Max (physical device).

When I fire up a FlushBar with `.show()`, the top navigation bar gets hidden during the fade in of the FlushBar, and shows up again only when the FlushBar starts to FadeOut.

This is how I fire up the FlushBar:

```
Flushbar(
  message: 'message',
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
  leftBarIndicatorColor: AppTheme.colorRed, // Custom color.
  flushbarPosition: position,
)..show(context);
```

GIF below demonstrating the error:

[image: Top navigation gets hidden when FlushBar gets shown]

Comment: Is it doing the same behaviour when you explicitly set the flushbarPosition to FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM.

Comment: You should provide more code, this is probably related with your entire `build()` function so we need to see it.

Comment: Looks like the widget is pushing everything up, you could try wrapping the page with a safe area or using a stack to show your widget over the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was related to the BuildContext of the parent not being persisted to it's children due to poor development choices, so the Flushbar was using the context of the Parent, which then pushed the Child upwards.